# session_regenerate_id(): Failed to create(read) session ID: user (path: )

Tags: magento-enterprise, session

After installing magento enterprise, getting following error:

> Recoverable Error: session_regenerate_id(): Failed to create(read) session ID: user (path: )  in /www/spree/helloworld/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 514

after googling it has come across some SO & GitHub posts such as ( https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2873 ) and these all mention casting the read() return value in SaveHandler to string - but I cannot seem to find this function/class in the enterprise edition?